# How to make Imagefield slideshow display full width

Tags: javascript

I use Drupal 7.20 and try to make my imagefield just like [PULLANDBEAR](http://www.pullandbear.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/category/pullandbeargb/en/pullandbear/29020?reload=0.5291279576444757#/1965068/BASIC%20LINEN%20TOP).

This is what I've already done: I'm using field slideshow to make node slideshow (this works as I want it to).

Then I want my image on click to open a bigger image that respects width and height (this part is really confusing).

Can someone give me the right directions or clues? I still haven't found the right ones. Maybe I used the wrong keyword(s) to find them? Right now I'm still using a trial and error approach as in the question [How to zoom in an image using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581784/how-to-zoom-in-an-image-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used the field slideshow module, but if it allows you to select the image style, then you could use the Lightbox2 module http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2. Lightbox 2 is not the only option for displaying the image in an overlay/popup type thing, there are many, here is a comparison of some of them http://drupal.org/node/266126. I just mention lightbox2 specifically as it is the one I usually use.

Comment: nice solutions, but already tried that. but still don't meet my need. maybe i miss something in configure it. i need to display image full width just like this [link] (http://www.pullandbear.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/category/pullandbearid/en/pullandbear/29016/DRESSES?NEWCOLLECTION#/2243517/GAUZE%20DRESS%20WITH%20FRONT%20DETAIL) when image click. it display in full width

Comment: I have not seen a module that implements that functionality specifically sorry.

Comment: dear @2pha, i try something like this (modify clue from Smb007) [link]http://jsfiddle.net/ADdqZ/. but still not as smooth as pullandbear and still looking how to creat an arrow to make it a slider. i'm still new to jQuery. ps(pardon for my english)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5pnku/1/ You may have to change the way the position is calculated though.

Comment: thanks @2pha for the script. now i try to find how to combine it with lightbox. so the larger image show in popup. maybe someone in this site already try it. it's been a week and more trying to find some clues. still need lot to learn jQuery :p

Answer (score 0):

I think [Cloud Zoom](https://www.drupal.org/project/cloud_zoom) should work. It's what's used on a lot of fashion magazine-style websites. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> ... integrates the [Cloud Zoom](http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/cloud-zoom.htm) JQuery addon with CCK [ImageField](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield) and [ImageCache](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache) (or Drupal 7's core Image module).

This addon provides a small, thumbnail sized image, with an on-hover popup, zoomed and centred on a larger version of the image.